# com.google.firebase - java.lang.AssertionError: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyPairGenerator RSA implementation not found

Tags: android, google-play-services

Getting this crash on Nexus 4 - Android 4.1.2:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyPairGenerator RSA implementation not found
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zza.zzbms(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzcxd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzcxa(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzbmu(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzcww(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzaa(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyPairGenerator RSA implementation not found
       at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
       at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
       at java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyPairGenerator.java:85)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zza.zzbms(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzcxd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzcxa(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzbmu(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzcww(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzaa(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Thought it might have to do with latest google-services, I'm only using google-analytics:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
```

Anyone encountered this issue and know the solution?

Comment: I can't provide any info except to say that I see quite a lot of these in our Fabric/Crashlytics data coming from Android 4.0.3, 4.0.4 and 4.1.2 devices, particularly older Kindle Fire models.  I regularly update the various play-services libraries as part of our app updates; the error has been showing up for quite a long time now and still occur with play-services v9.4.0.